# Populate empty grid columns with data from database

Tags: javascript, php, css-grid

On my home page is an empty grid with 3 columns per row:
[image]

On a different page, the user can fill in specific information so that these squares are filled in with said info (These squares represent projects of students/schools). I already managed to send the data to the database. But now I am a bit stuck, because how should I populate these empty squares with the data from the database?

*The PHP for sending data to the db*

```
<?php 
include('../general.config.php');

print_r($_POST);
$title = $_POST['title'];
$summary = $_POST['summary']; 
$shortSummary = $_POST['shortSummary']; 
$type = $_POST['type']; 


    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `project`( `type`, `short_summary`, `summary`, `title`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $query->bindPARAM(1,$type, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindPARAM(2,$shortSummary, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindPARAM(3,$summary, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindPARAM(4,$title, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($query->execute())
    echo "succes!";
else
    echo "NO SUCCES!";

?>
```

*The grid layout*

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

*This square will eventually look like this:*
[image]

**For this I would like to use vanilla JS as much as possible**

**EDIT**
*How my data gets retrieved from the database:*

```
  <?php 
    include('../general.config.php');

    $sql = "SELECT `type`, `short_summary`, `title` FROM `project`";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row["type"]. $row["short_summary"]. $row["title"]. "<br>";
    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
?>
```

*Where the data should be put* **But for every new data entry should be a new box for in the grid:**

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <?php foreach($result as $key=>$value): ?>
        <div class="box"> <?= $key; ?> </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

*How it is on the website* **It just shows the data on the top left corner and not in the grid**
[image]

Comment: You'll fetch the data from the database via a `SELECT` Mysql Query and then loop over any results to effectively print the boxes.

Comment: @Darren So first in a new php i'll have to fetch the data, and then in another js file i can loop over this and set it's data to the empty grid boxes?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to query the data from the database, an example from w3schools:

```php
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

And then you can insert it into the HTML with a for each to populate according to the data you have, in your code it would look like this:

```html
<div class="grid-container">
<?php foreach($array as $key=>$value): ?>
    <div class="box"> <?= $key; ?> </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm not sure how that php inside html works

Comment: The HTML is inside the PHP file and then you can use the opening "<php" and closing "?>" tags to indicate that you are going to insert php code.

Comment: Sorry, but now got a PHP file which correctly gets the data. But what now? In that same PHP file should be the HTML? And then according to what u said it should populate my grid?

Comment: I will! But the data is not populating the grid? Or do i need to set the key and value ? Sorry totally new when it comes to backend..

Comment: Sorry I thought the issue was resolved. $array will be the list of values you get back from the database, and then you will get the key and value such as: $key = id, $value = 1. So just replace $array with the list you get back from the database and you should be good!

Comment: Made an edit, i replaced $array with $result  (the list i get from the db)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you're using, you'd want to modify the data fetching/handling to this:

```
include('../general.config.php');

$sql = "SELECT `type`, `short_summary`, `title` FROM `project`";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$data = []; // data array
if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

As you can see, we've created a new `$data` array to hold the results for later. When we loop the rows from our mysql query, we add them to the `$data` array by `$data[] = $row;`.

Now for your printing/echoing;

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <?php foreach($data as $key => $value): ?>
        <div class="box"> <?= $key; ?> </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

**Note:** All of your information will be held in the `$value` variable while you're looping. To see what data you have access to you can simply `print_r($value)` and then harness it as an array. I.e. `echo $value['title'];`.